# Printer not "enabled" - Samsung ML-2010 - Ubuntu LTS 16.04

Tags: 16.04, printing, samsung

Help please. I'm a new Ubuntu user, and I'm having a recurrent problem with my printer. It's chronically not enabled. I can't print. When I look under system settings > printers, I see my printer, but it's got the paused sign (||) showing. I right click and "enabled" is not checked. I click enabled and get the check box, but moments later, it's paused again. I've tried faffing about properties > policies, but that doesn't help.

Any ideas? I'm happy to share some diagnostics if anyone can tell me what's relevant.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have similar problem in 16.04, but with Samsung ML-1641.  Printer won't stay "Enabled" for longer than one printing job.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Get your printer usb device id with lsusb command in shell
2. Open /etc/default/tlp with any text editor under sudo
3. Uncomment line 178 and paste your printer usb device id, and the line should look like:

```
USB_BLACKLIST="04e8:3292"
```

This will prevent printer from begin auto-suspended

Answer (score 0):

had to install Smart Panel on Ubuntu 16.04 Mate
in order to print - without Smart Panel printing
with ML-1640 was impossible